# Are these value template parameters same?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename std::list<int>::value_type value>
int silly()
{
    return value;
}

template<typename int value>
int silly2()
{
    return value;
}

template<int value>
int silly3()
{
    return value;
}
```

Question1> Is the `value_type` of `std::list<int>` `int`?

Question2> Are these three `sillyX` function in fact equivalent to each other?

Comment: @AJG85- While I agree that the second of these is invalid, the first and third are perfectly legal - they're non-type template arguments.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Well then it seems MSVC accepts all three ... MSVC accepts a lot though. The third is fine, the first and second are what looked like something that shouldn't compile to me. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: @AJG85: The first is valid because `typename` can be put in front of any name with a *nested-name-specifier* (that is, `Class::name` or `Namespace::name`). It can't be put in front of an unqualified type name, so the second is invalid without one of Microsoft's many "extensions".

Answer (score 3):

For starters, the code

```
template<typename int value>
    int silly2()
{
    return value;
}
```

Is not legal, because the template argument definition isn't allowed.  You need to either parameterize the template over an integer value by saying `template <int value>` or over a type argument by saying `template <typename value>`.  The reason that `typename` is allowed inside of the first template is that it's using the second meaning of `typename`, namely, that what comes next names a type.

Besides this, yes, (1) and (3) are the same, because the C++ ISO spec requires that `std::list<int>::value_type` be `int`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1: Yes , `container::value_type` is `typedef` of type of element it contains

Answer 2: your `silly2()` is ill formed since non-type parameters of template don't require `typename` unless type is qualified and dependent on some type parameter

In your first form though :

```
template<typename std::list<int>::value_type value> //you don't require typename since qualified name value_type isn't dependent, so it's avoided by compiler I guess
int silly()
```

Comment: @q0987: That compiler has many "extensions" that accept all sorts of invalid code. There is an option to disable most of them, if you want a better chance of writing portable code.